# Where to get the detailed code of MMA for grid mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, computational-geometry, mesh

I know `DelaunayMesh` can triangulate the specified area, but I can't see the code and partition idea of this built-in function. I want to know how to get the source code of grid generation or where to get the detailed code of MMA grid generation.

I've done a related code before, but I want to get more detailed code on Meshing.

```
isInCircleRight[circleCenter_?ListQ, R_, point_?ListQ] := 
 Module[{maxPointInCircleX}, 
  maxPointInCircleX = circleCenter[[1]] + R; 
  If[point[[1]] >= maxPointInCircleX, True, False]]
(*SetAttributes[drop,HoldFirst];
drop[as_?AssociationQ,list_?ListQ]:=Delete[as,Transpose@{list}]*)
x = {{211.18`}, {211.28`}, {211.1`}, {211.38`}, {211.45`}, {211.23`}, \
{211.31`}, {210.98`}, {211.13`}, {211.39`}, {211.06`}, {211.51`}, \
{211.19`}, {211.26`}, {211.32`}, {211.1`}, {211.01`}, {211.39`}, \
{211.48`}, {211.17`}, {211.21`}, {211.25`}, {211.29`}, {210.91`}, \
{211.57`}, {211.15`}, {211.19`}, {211.23`}, {211.27`}, {211.31`}, \
{211.34`}, {211.06`}, {211.47`}, {211.13`}, {211.17`}, {211.21`}, \
{211.25`}, {211.29`}, {211.32`}, {211.53`}, {210.96`}, {211.11`}, \
{211.15`}, {211.19`}, {211.23`}, {211.27`}, {211.3`}, {211.34`}, \
{211.38`}, {211.04`}};
y = {{-47.97`}, {-47.97`}, {-47.98`}, {-47.98`}, {-48.`}, {-48.01`}, \
{-48.01`}, {-48.02`}, {-48.02`}, {-48.02`}, {-48.03`}, {-48.03`}, \
{-48.04`}, {-48.04`}, {-48.05`}, {-48.06`}, {-48.07`}, {-48.07`}, \
{-48.07`}, {-48.08`}, {-48.08`}, {-48.08`}, {-48.08`}, {-48.09`}, \
{-48.09`}, {-48.1`}, {-48.1`}, {-48.1`}, {-48.1`}, {-48.1`}, \
{-48.1`}, {-48.11`}, {-48.11`}, {-48.12`}, {-48.12`}, {-48.12`}, \
{-48.12`}, {-48.12`}, {-48.12`}, {-48.12`}, {-48.14`}, {-48.14`}, \
{-48.14`}, {-48.14`}, {-48.14`}, {-48.14`}, {-48.14`}, {-48.14`}, \
{-48.14`}, {-48.15`}};

data = MapThread[List, {x // Flatten, y // Flatten}];

Xmax = Max[x]; Xmin = Min[x]; Ymax = Max[y]; Ymin = Min[y];

upPoint = {Xmin - 0.01 + (Xmax + 0.02 - (Xmin - 0.01))/2, 
   Ymax + 0.02 + 0.4};
h = upPoint[[2]] - (Ymax + 0.02);
w = upPoint[[1]] - (Xmin - 0.01);
arc = ArcTan[h/w];
h1 = upPoint[[2]] - (Ymin - 0.01);
w1 = h1/arc;
leftPoint = {upPoint[[1]] - w1, Ymin - 0.01 - 0.1};
rightPoint = {upPoint[[1]] + w1, Ymin - 0.01 - 0.1};


Graphics[{Line[{{leftPoint[[1]], leftPoint[[2]]}, {rightPoint[[1]], 
     rightPoint[[2]]}}], 
  Line[{{rightPoint[[1]], rightPoint[[2]]}, {upPoint[[1]], 
     upPoint[[2]]}}], 
  Line[{{upPoint[[1]], upPoint[[2]]}, {leftPoint[[1]], 
     leftPoint[[2]]}}]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {210.5, -48.3}]

pointSet = SortBy[data, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &];
pointNum = Length[pointSet];

triangleList = <||>;
AssociateTo[triangleList, 1 -> <|1 -> leftPoint|>];
AssociateTo[triangleList[1], 2 -> rightPoint];
AssociateTo[triangleList[1], 3 -> upPoint];

tempBuffer = <||>;
triangles = <||>;
DtriangleNum = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= pointNum, i++,
 triangleNum = Length[triangleList];
 tempBuffer = <||>;
 (*ps={};*)
 dellists = {};

 For[j = 1, j <= triangleNum, j++,
  circ = Circumsphere[Values[triangleList[j]]];
  {circleCenter, R} = {First@circ, Last@circ};
  inCircle = Element[pointSet[[i]], Disk[circleCenter, R]];
  If[inCircle === True,
   temp = <||>;
   temp[1] = {triangleList[j, 1], triangleList[j, 2]}; 
   temp[2] = {triangleList[j, 1], triangleList[j, 3]}; 
   temp[3] = {triangleList[j, 2], triangleList[j, 3]};
   len = Length[tempBuffer];
   tempBuffer = Join[tempBuffer, KeyMap[# + len &, temp]];



   dellists = {dellists, j} // Flatten;,
   inRight = isInCircleRight[circleCenter, R, pointSet[[i]]]; 
   If[inRight === True,
    DtriangleNum = DtriangleNum + 1;

    triangles[DtriangleNum] = triangleList[j];]]
  ];

 triangleList = KeyDrop[triangleList, dellists];
 triangleList = 
  AssociationThread[
   Range[Length[triangleList]] -> Values[triangleList]];


 tempBuffer = Map[Append[#, 0] &, tempBuffer];

 tempBuffer = 
  AssociationThread[Range[Length[tempBuffer]] -> Values[tempBuffer]];
 If[Length[tempBuffer] != 0, 
  For[k = 1, k <= (Length[tempBuffer] - 1), k++, 
   For[ s = k + 1, s <= Length[tempBuffer], s++, 
    If[(tempBuffer[k] === tempBuffer[s]), 
     tempBuffer[k] = ReplacePart[tempBuffer[k], 3 -> 1]; 
     tempBuffer[s] = ReplacePart[tempBuffer[s], 3 -> 1];]]]

  ];

 rows = Position[tempBuffer, _?(Last[##] != 0 &), {1}, 
    Heads -> False][[All, 1, 1]];
 tempBuffer = KeyDrop[tempBuffer, rows];

 tempBuffer = 
  AssociationThread[Range[Length[tempBuffer]] -> Values[tempBuffer]];

 triangleNum = Length[triangleList];
 (*Print[triangleNum];*)
 For[w = 1, w <= Length[tempBuffer], w = w + 1,

  triangleList[triangleNum + w] = <||>;
  triangleList[triangleNum + w, 1] = pointSet[[i]]; 
  triangleList[triangleNum + w, 2] = tempBuffer[[w, 1]]; 
  triangleList[triangleNum + w, 3] = tempBuffer[[w, 2]];];
 triangleList = 
  AssociationThread[
   Range[Length[triangleList]] -> Values[triangleList]];


 ]

triangles = 
  Join[triangles, KeyMap[# + Length[triangles] &, triangleList]];


n = Length[triangles];
del2list = {};
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, flag = 0; 
  row = (Position[triangles[i][[;; , 1]], leftPoint[[1]]][[All, 1, 
     1]]);
  If[row != {}, 
   If[(First@triangles[i][[row, 2]]) === leftPoint[[2]], flag = 1, 
    flag = 0]]; 
  row = (Position[triangles[i][[;; , 1]], rightPoint[[1]]][[All, 1, 
     1]]); If[row != {}, 
   If[(First@triangles[i][[row, 2]]) === rightPoint[[2]], flag = 1, 
    flag = 0]];

  row = (Position[triangles[i][[;; , 1]], upPoint[[1]]][[All, 1, 1]]);
   If[row != {}, 
   If[(First@triangles[i][[row, 2]]) === upPoint[[2]], flag = 1, 
    flag = 0]]; If[flag === 1, del2list = {del2list, i} // Flatten]];
triangles = KeyDrop[triangles, del2list];

triangles = 
  AssociationThread[Range[Length[triangles]] -> Values[triangles]];

n = Length[triangles];

Graphics@Table[
  Line[Append[Values@triangles[i], First[(Values@triangles[i])]]], {i,
    1, n}]
DelaunayMesh[data, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> {Thick, Red}, {0, All} -> {Black, 
     PointSize[0.02]}}, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematica uses [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) as a 2D mesh generator. The interface to triangle is in [TriangleLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/TriangleLink/guide/TriangleLink.html). Triangle comes with source code and you can find that [here](http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/triangle.zip). Triangle is also used as a basis for `DelaunayMesh`, if I am not mistaken.

If you want a book then "[Delaunay Mesh Generation](https://doi.org/10.1201/b12987)", by Cheng, Dey and Shewchuck (CRC Press) is a starting point.

Should you want to write your own mesh generator you can easily make use of that in the finite element package. There are also other packages that make their own mesh for FEM, for example [Pinti's MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) or `DistMesh`, which is a simple but high quality mesh generator that is implemented in the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns). Both of these return an [ElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html). That can be used for `NDSolve`, `NIntegrate` and `NDEigensystem` etc.

I am looking forward to see your mesher ;-)